# Pentaho adhoc reporting functions

Tags: reporting, pentaho, adhoc

I am doing reporting on a dataset but I only want the report to show the count function instead of all the values and, in the end, a line with the count.

Can it be done?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question : do you want just the count or the data and the count?

Comment: I want just the count.
All I can do is to represent all the values and, at the end, a line with the count. But I wished just the counts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you may have a datasource myds  :

select count(*) from mytable

Then you create a simple parameter mycount and a query component myquery.

Assign myds to the property Datasource of myquery and mycount to the property Result Var

If you want to display the value, add a text component mytext and make it listen to the parameter mycount. 
In its Expression property, enter the following code :

```
function(){return(mycount.toString(););}
```